# What can can be done to get consecutive counts here in the most efficient way?

Tags: python, pandas, feature-extraction, data-science

I'm a beginner in Python Data Science. I'm working on clickstream data and trying to count the consecutive clicks on an item in a given session. I'm getting the cumulative sum in 'Block' column. After that I'm aggregating on Block to get the count on each block. In the end I want to groupby Session and Item and aggregate the block count since there may be cases(Sid=6 here) where an item comes consecutively m times at first and again after other items, it comes consecutively n times. So the consecutive count should be 'm+n'.

Here is the dataset-

```
    Sid                    Tstamp     Itemid
0     1  2014-04-07T10:51:09.277Z  214536502
1     1  2014-04-07T10:54:09.868Z  214536500
2     1  2014-04-07T10:54:46.998Z  214536506
3     1  2014-04-07T10:57:00.306Z  214577561
4     2  2014-04-07T13:56:37.614Z  214662742
5     2  2014-04-07T13:57:19.373Z  214662742
6     2  2014-04-07T13:58:37.446Z  214825110
7     2  2014-04-07T13:59:50.710Z  214757390
8     2  2014-04-07T14:00:38.247Z  214757407
9     2  2014-04-07T14:02:36.889Z  214551617
10    3  2014-04-02T13:17:46.940Z  214716935
11    3  2014-04-02T13:26:02.515Z  214774687
12    3  2014-04-02T13:30:12.318Z  214832672
13    4  2014-04-07T12:09:10.948Z  214836765
14    4  2014-04-07T12:26:25.416Z  214706482
15    6  2014-04-03T10:44:35.672Z  214821275
16    6  2014-04-03T10:45:01.674Z  214821275
17    6  2014-04-03T10:45:29.873Z  214821371
18    6  2014-04-03T10:46:12.162Z  214821371
19    6  2014-04-03T10:46:57.355Z  214821371
20    6  2014-04-03T10:53:22.572Z  214717089
21    6  2014-04-03T10:53:49.875Z  214563337
22    6  2014-04-03T10:55:19.267Z  214706462
23    6  2014-04-03T10:55:47.327Z  214821371
24    6  2014-04-03T10:56:30.520Z  214821371
25    6  2014-04-03T10:57:19.331Z  214821371
26    6  2014-04-03T10:57:39.433Z  214819762
```

Here is my code-

```
k['Block'] =( k['Itemid'] != k['Itemid'].shift(1) ).astype(int).cumsum()
y=k.groupby('Block').count()
z=k.groupby(['Sid','Itemid']).agg({"y[Count]": lambda x: x.sum()})
```

Comment: Ca you add desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't this work?

```
k.groupby(['Sid', 'Itemid']).Block.count()
Sid  Itemid   
1    214536500    1
     214536502    1
     214536506    1
     214577561    1
2    214551617    1
     214662742    2
     214757390    1
     214757407    1
     214825110    1
3    214716935    1
     214774687    1
     214832672    1
4    214706482    1
     214836765    1
6    214563337    1
     214706462    1
     214717089    1
     214819762    1
     214821275    2
     214821371    6
Name: Block, dtype: int64
```

Comment: The 2nd output is what I wanted. Thank you :)

Comment: Can you tell me the significance of using reset_index() there?

Comment: I think `reset_index()` is not necessary. You can omit it. Mybe better is use `reset_index()` in the end `k.groupby(['Sid', 'Itemid']).Block.count().reset_index()`

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can:

```
k['Block'] =( k['Itemid'] != k['Itemid'].shift(1) ).astype(int).cumsum()
#print k
z=k.groupby(['Sid','Itemid', 'Block']).size().groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().reset_index(name='sum_counts') 
print z
    Sid     Itemid  sum_counts
0     1  214536500           1
1     1  214536502           1
2     1  214536506           1
3     1  214577561           1
4     2  214551617           1
5     2  214662742           2
6     2  214757390           1
7     2  214757407           1
8     2  214825110           1
9     3  214716935           1
10    3  214774687           1
11    3  214832672           1
12    4  214706482           1
13    4  214836765           1
14    6  214701242           1
15    6  214826623           1
16    7  214826715           1
17    7  214826835           1
18    8  214838855           2
19    9  214576500           3
20   11  214563337           1
21   11  214706462           1
22   11  214717089           1
23   11  214819762           1
24   11  214821275           2
25   11  214821371           6
```